# Compare HashMap<String, Double> and List<ArrayList<String>> in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a `HashMap<String, Double>` like `arr1[]-{AA=0.05, BB=0.031, CC=0.056}` and `List<ArrayList<String>>` like  `arr2[]-[ [AA,BB,CC] , [BB, CC] , [AA, CC]].` I want to take output like `List<ArrayList<Double>>`.It will be `[ [0.05,0.031,0.056] , [0.031, 0.056] , [0.05, 0.056]].`
I used ,

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr2.size(); i++) {
if (arr1.containsKey(arr2.get(i))) {
```

But, not works. How to do it?

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: I edited. I used for loop to check one by one values from arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Map<String, Double> mappings = //get mappings
List<ArrayList<String>> source = //get source
List<ArrayList<Double>> target = new ArrayList<>();
for(ArrayList<String> sourceElement : source){
    ArrayList<Double> targetElememt = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String sourceElementString : sourceElement){
        targetElememt.add(mappings.get(sourceElementString));
    }
    target.add(targetElememt);
}
System.out.println(target);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My final output need to be `List<ArrayList<Double>>` . If I used this code  in ` target.add(targetElememt);`  cannot add values.

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly.. :)

Comment: It works fine. Thank you very much for your prompt reply.

Answer (score 3):

This could be achieved easily using [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) :

```
lists.stream()
    .map(list -> list.stream().map(map::get).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Assume that `lists` here is your `List<ArrayList<String>>` and that `map` is your `HashMap<String, Double>`, this would return the `List<ArrayList<Double>>` that you expect.

I'd like to add that I have no clue why you want an `ArrayList` in your list, but if there is no specific reason use `Collectors.toList()` instead of `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)`.